# Getting a "Mismatch error" when scanning a File and assigning them to an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

Given a file that is a student roster where the first line is the number of students in the class and in the following lines I am provided with their name, ID, and age such as the following:

```
    5
    Mary, 1010, 15
    Ben, 1119, 16
    Sam, 2278, 15
    Alex, 3245, 15
    Mia, 4448, 16
```

I'm supposed to create an array of student objects but I receive a "mismatch error" when I try to compile my code.

I have tried the following, but I am not sure what about my code is wrong.

```
public class Classroom_Runner{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

File roster = new File("info.txt");
Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(roster);
Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
//roster.split(", ");

//String insideFile = "";
int sizeClass = 0;
Classroom[] Students = new Classroom[0];

while(scanFile.hasNext()){
    sizeClass =scanFile.nextInt();
    String name = scanFile.next(); //<-- This would be line 35
    int ID = scanFile.nextInt();
    int age = scanFile.nextInt();

    Classroom student = new Classroom( name, age, ID);

}
    for(int i = 0; i<Students.length;i++){
            System.out.println(Students[i]);}
}
}
```

The actual output is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
            at Classroom_Runner.main(Classroom_Runner.java:35)
```

but the expected output should be:

```
    Mary, 1010, 15
    Ben, 1119, 16
    Sam, 2278, 15
    Alex, 3245, 15
    Mia, 4448, 16
```

Comment: `roster.nextInt();`, `roster` is not a `Scanner`, it is a `File`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad.

Comment: your first line is different from others.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "1010," is not an `int` because of its comma `,`, and therefore the following line doesn't run:

```
int ID = scanFile.nextInt();
```

Either remove the commas in the input file, or use `next()`, remove the comma with `substring()` and then cast it to `int`.

An other, better solution would be to use `scanFile.nextLine()` at each iteration and then get the different values into an array with `String.split(", ")`, before converting those that need to be converted to `int`.

Comment: I'm actually not allowed to tamper with the text file, instead I was told to use .split() . However, when I implemented it, i would get "can not find symbol" error or String van not be converted to Classroom

Answer (score 0):

```
        sizeClass =scanFile.nextInt();
        String name = scanFile.next(); 

        String temp = scanFile.next();
        temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length() -1);

        int realID = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        //rest of your code
```

You should get rid of the trailing comma, in order to catch the integers in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily using `Files.lines()` and Java Streams:

```
Classroom[] students = Files.lines(Paths.get("info.txt")).skip(1)
        .map(line -> line.split(", "))
        .filter(parts -> parts.length == 3)
        .map(parts -> new Classroom(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Integer.parseInt(parts[2])))
        .toArray(Classroom[]::new);
```

First you read all the lines (skipping the first one, you don't need that). You then split each line by `,` in the single parts. To prevent an `IndexOutOfBoundException` only process lines with 3 parts. At the end you map each line to your `Classroom` object and collect all to an array.

The result for the input you provided will be this:

```
Classroom[name='Mary', age=1010, id=15]
Classroom[name='Ben', age=1119, id=16]
Classroom[name='Sam', age=2278, id=15]
Classroom[name='Alex', age=3245, id=15]
Classroom[name='Mia', age=4448, id=16]
```